# ggplot-How to create a legend using row&column names

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data frame which I want to pass first two columns rows and
variable column names to create legend.

Inside of `df` I have group of dataset in which they grouped with letters from `a` to `h`. In particular, I want to pass `AC`&`AR` columns rows as names in combination with `DQ0:DQ2` variables and they should be shown in the legend with that format. 
something like 78_256_DQ0, and 78_256_DQ1 and 78_256_DQ2  for data group `a` 
and same for the rest of `letters` in the `df`.

my reproducible `df` like this;

```
df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1,function(x){
AC <- as.character(rep(rep(c(78,110),each=10),times=3))
AR <- as.character(rep(rep(c(256,320,384),each=20),times=1))
V <- rep(c(seq(2,40,length.out=5),seq(-2,-40,length.out=5)),times=2)
DQ0 = sort(replicate(6, runif(10,0.001:1)))
DQ1 = sort(replicate(6, runif(10,0.001:1)))
DQ2 = sort(replicate(6, runif(10,0.001:1)))
No  =  c(replicate(1,rep(letters[1:6],each=10)))
data.frame(AC,AR,V,DQ0,DQ1,DQ2,No)
}))
```

> head(df)

```
    AC  AR     V         DQ0        DQ1        DQ2 No
1   78 256   2.0 0.003944916 0.00902776 0.00228837  a
2   78 256  11.5 0.006629239 0.01739512 0.01649540  a
3   78 256  21.0 0.048515226 0.02034436 0.04525160  a
4   78 256  30.5 0.079483625 0.04346118 0.04778420  a
5   78 256  40.0 0.099462310 0.04430493 0.05086738  a
6   78 256  -2.0 0.103686255 0.04440260 0.09931459  a
*****************************************************
library(reshape2)
df_new <- melt(df,id=c("V","No"),measure=c("DQ0","DQ1","DQ2"))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df_new,aes(y=value,x=V,group=No,colour=No))+
geom_point()+
geom_line()
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

after @...  answer I made a little bit progress. His solution is partially ok. Because when we `melt` names

```
df$names <- interaction(df$AC,df$AR,names(df)[4:6])
df_new <- melt(df,id=c("V","No","names1"),measure=c("DQ0","DQ1","DQ2"))
```

this command plots 4 rows for each group `a` to `h`.

the output becomes like this;

> head(df)

```
  AC  AR    V         DQ0        DQ1         DQ2 No     names
1 78 256  2.0 0.002576547 0.04294134 0.008302918  a 78.256.DQ0
2 78 256 11.5 0.010150299 0.04570650 0.011749370  a 78.256.DQ1
3 78 256 21.0 0.012540026 0.06977744 0.013887357  a 78.256.DQ2
4 78 256 30.5 0.036532977 0.11460343 0.071172301  a 78.256.DQ0
5 78 256 40.0 0.042801967 0.11518191 0.073756228  a 78.256.DQ1
6 78 256 -2.0 0.043275144 0.13033194 0.076569977  a 78.256.DQ2
**************************************************************
```

and with modification of the plot command

```
ggplot(df_new,aes(y=value,x=V,lty=variable,colour=names))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()
```

the output format which I prefer is something I can refer all rows of DQ0,DQ1 and DQ2 inside of each group. Any suggestions?

**last condition**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

u can use `df$names <- interaction(v$AC,v$AR,DQ0)` and then also set `names` in you `melt` command as `id`. Later you use `color=names` in your `aes` function.

So, this will add a column name with a combination of the defined columns. You can also set a `sep='_'` if you prefer over `.`.
If you now use this column for colouring, you will get those labels as legend names.

Comment: thanks for answer. Can you elaborate your solution a little bit. `v` is the `df `?

Comment: actually, yes, overlooked the definition of data frame and thought I spotted a `v`.

Comment: @aoronbarlow hope this solved you problem and made it more clear?

Comment: @ok I come to some point after your solution. I made this 
`df$names <- interaction(df$AC,df$AR,names(df)[4:6])`
which gives mixed up combinations of `AC`,`AR` and `DQ0:DQ2` under `names` column and when I `melt` them and plot `ggplot` the result is somehow close but little bit more effort I think is needed.

Comment: what I need is three additional column maybe something like `names1` `names2` and `names3` and under them `DQ0`,`DQ1`, and `DQ2` combinations with `AC` and `AR`columns.

Comment: yeap. I made this 
`df$names1 <- interaction(df$AC,df$AR,names(df)[4])`
`df$names2 <- interaction(df$AC,df$AR,names(df)[5])`

and inside of `melt`  I added ` id=c("V","No","names1","names2")` 

but I got error which says ` Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:V, value, variable`...

why?

Answer (score 0):

finally I found a way using `gather` from `dplyr`.

```
df_gather <-   df %>% gather(DQ, value,-No, -AC, -AR, -V)
```

and using `interaction` function from `@drmariod` answer

```
df_gather$names <- interaction(df_gather$AC,df_gather$AR,df_gather$DQ)
```

and here is the result of this question:)
[image]